# Soap - List of one string is sended as string

Tags: java, php, string, soap, wsdl

I'm sending from Java backend via SOAP an ArrayList of Strings to PHP client.

**WSDL:**

```
<xs:element name="getSearchHintResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="hint">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="text" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

It is working fine, when I'm sending more then one String, but when is only one String sended, then php side didn't recognize, that it is an Array of String and SOAP (or PHP?) somehow converts it to one String.

**Php log of one String:**

```
object(stdClass)#260 (1) {
    ["hint"]=>
    object(stdClass)#261 (1) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(5) "ales "
    }
}
```

**Php log with more Strings:**

```
object(stdClass)#260 (1) {
    ["hint"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#261 (1) {
            ["text"]=>
            string(4) "ale  "
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#262 (1) {
            ["text"]=>
            string(5) "ales "
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility, how can I fix this on Java backend side (where WSDL is created) or do I need to force php dev to check it for String?

EDIT:

**Java Endpoint:**

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getSearchHintRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public GetSearchHintResponse getSearchHintRequest(@RequestPayload GetSearchHintRequest request) throws Exception {
        GetSearchHintResponse response = new GetSearchHintResponse();
        List<GetSearchHintResponse.Hint> hints = response.getHint();
        Collection<? extends String> hintsStr = searchComponent.getSearchHint(request.getBeginning(),
                request.getCollections(), request.getHintCount());
        for (String hintStr : hintsStr) {
            GetSearchHintResponse.Hint hint = new GetSearchHintResponse.Hint();
            hint.setText(hintStr + "\t");
            hints.add(hint);
        }
        return response;
}
```

Comment: why is it so bad for you if it gets converted to a single string?

Comment: Php dev is expecting Array, but if it is single String, there is no array(2) {...} and he wants to fix that on my side. This is for suggesting mechanism in fulltext search and if I send him only one suggestion, then that suggestion it is not shown.

Comment: you could check for the length on your side and if its just 1 element, you add an empty string (`""`) to the array. i think that should solve it at first, but i am not sure about the impact on php dev

Comment: I tried that now. It is little ugly in code, but it is working. I thought, that there will be an empty row with no text, but there is only that one expected text. Nice work, you can send it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: if you provide the code, i might be able to improve it a bit and include it in the answer

Comment: Can you capture how the actual messages are going? What's parsing it on PHP side?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Edited

Comment: @Tamas Rev I dont have access to php code.

Comment: is that the updated code? i don't see any check fot he amount of elements

Comment: That is old code, I was expecting update from you in answer. :D Updated is like this: if (hints.size()==1) {
    GetSearchHintResponse.Hint hint = new GetSearchHintResponse.Hint();
    hint.setText("");
    hints.add(hint);
   } //before return statement.

Comment: not having a better solution lol

Comment: You don't understand me. I just want from you, to write an answer (via "Post your answer" button) with your answer in comments above to close this question. For your reward, it will acceept your answer and give some votes up, to give you your well deserved reputation points :) and maybe some badges :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As XtremeBaumer mentioned in comments:

> you could check for the length on your side and if its just 1 element, you add an empty string ("") to the array. i think that should solve it at first, but i am not sure about the impact on php dev – XtremeBaumer Jan 12 at 8:30

It was little dirty way, with empty div, but it works.